# How to use one query if _GET isn't exist and use other query if it is?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want something strange. If someone opens `index.php` page, `$select` must be `full`, . But if someone opens `index.php?var=4 page`, `$select` must be other, with var `from _GET`.

I have this code now, but it works only if `?var=3 exists`.

What am I missing?

```
foreach($_GET as $name=>$value)
{
    if($name == 'lvl') {
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[lvl]);
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT * from $table where lvl='$value'");
    }
    else {
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT name,image,lvl,team,icon FROM $table");
    }
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
   $name = mysql_real_escape_string($row['name']);
```

Comment: Where are you using parameter `var` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are depending on the existence of a `?lvl=...` in your code.
Also, using the mysql-functions is not recommended, since they are deprecated. Consider changing to mysqli or PDO. For this example, I'll still use mysql-functions.

Better to use this:

```
if (isset($_GET['lvl'])) { // Check to see whether or not lvl is set in url
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lvl']);
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE lvl = '$value';");
} else { // If not, use other query
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT name, image, lvl, team, icon FROM $table;");
}

while ...
```